# ¿Cómo puedo desconectar un evento de un control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando en el llenado de campos de un formulario y tengo un `ComboBox` que hace referencia al personal de ventas y tengo el evento asociado `SelectedIndexChanged` que desencadena una busqueda luego de cambiar de valor.
Lo que quiero es evitar que se desencadene ese evento, porque al hacer el `Load` del formulario en una primera carga obtengo un error al tratar de hacer la busqueda asociada, ya que el `ComboBox` no tiene aún un valor valido.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedo hacer asi:

```
combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

...y reconectarlo despues asi:

```
combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged += combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Por supuesto, en este caso, debe tiene un evento come este:

```
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   . . .
}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias Clay. Una consulta, ¿eso funciona para cualquier control y para cualquier evento? o existen algunas restricciones.

Comment: Si, en la misma manera.

Comment: Genia, nuevamente muchas gracias.